# Gentics Mesh - Import / Export project from one instance to another

Tags: gentics-mesh

Gentics Mesh Version : v1.4.8

**Question :**

Is it possible to export a specific project with all the schemas/micro-schemas definition associated to it and the all nodes contribute from one instance of Gentics mesh and to import to another one?

What I would like to achieve is to export a project with its data from Gentics Mesh instance A (dev) to another Gentics Mesh instance B (prod).

**What I've tried :**

I tried to export/import using the [API described](https://getmesh.io/docs/administration-guide/#_backup_recovery) (export/import). The export from instance A seems to be fine, generating this gzip json file. I'm placing this file into the instance B at location /data/export and launching the import. The logs seems OK. However as soon as I access the interface, I keep getting an infinite loop of pop up error message (because of 404s).

If I'm not getting wrong, the export feature is exporting the all content of the graphDB? Is there a way to export only a part of it? Like a specific project. If this feature doesn't exist, what should I custom implement in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial import/export is currently not possible. We are already tracking this feature request via https://github.com/gentics/mesh-incubator/issues/77

Comment: Ok cool. Is this idea of exporting from one instance to import to another one should be still possible with a backup (/api/v2/admin/graphdb/backup) or an export (POST /api/v2/admin/graphdb/export) ? What is the difference between the two features ?

Comment: If you want to import a backup you can use these endpoints. Backup will create a tgz of your whole graphdb directory and export will create compressed json export of your database. The json export does not contain indices the graphdb does. The export is useful if you want to reimport the db to shrink the sparse files. This is especially useful after a large deletion operation.